# Generic Method in C# ('variable' where a 'method group' was expected)

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to write a function that takes the input from the user and processes it according to a specified function.  For that I write a generic method and pass it a (generic) delegate function, but get the `"Expression denotes a 'variable', where a 'method group' was expected"` error.

In particular, I have a class of polynomials with integer coefficients called `PolynomialZ`.  I want the user to specify the coefficients from the command line:

```csharp
delegate T InputFunction<T>();

public static TRetType GetInput<TRetType, TFuncType>(TFuncType inputFunc,
                                                     string greetingMsg,
                                                     string errMsg="Input Error.")
{
    Console.Write(greetingMsg);
    try {
        return inputFunc();
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine(errMsg);
        return GetInput<TRetType, TFuncType>(inputFunc, greetingMsg, errMsg);
    }
}

public static PolynomialZ GetPolynomial()
{
    var greetingMsg = "Please input coefficients of the polynomial:";
    InputFunction<PolynomialZ> inputFunc = delegate {
        string inputStr = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        return inputStr == "" ? null : new PolynomialZ(inputStr
                                                       .Split()
                                                       .Select(c => Int32.Parse(c))
                                                       .ToArray());
    };
    return GetInput<PolynomialZ, InputFunction<PolynomialZ>>(inputFunc, greetingMsg);
}
```

According to monodevelop, the error is caused by the `return inputFunc();` line.  If I remove the parenthesis and leave just the `return inputFunc;` statement, I get, perhaps unsurprisingly, `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'TFuncType' to 'TRetType'"` error.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's the working version (thanks to @JonSkeet):

```csharp
public static TRetType GetInput<TRetType>(Func<TRetType> inputFunc,
                                          string greetingMsg,
                                          string errMsg="Input Error.")
{
    Console.Write(greetingMsg);
    try {
        return inputFunc();
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine(errMsg);
        return GetInput<TRetType>(inputFunc, greetingMsg, errMsg);
    }
}

public static PolynomialZ GetPolynomial()
{
    var greetingMsg = "Please input coefficients of the polynomial:";
    InputFunction<PolynomialZ> inputFunc = delegate {
        string inputStr = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        return inputStr == "" ? null : new PolynomialZ(inputStr
                                                       .Split()
                                                       .Select(c => Int32.Parse(c))
                                                       .ToArray());
    };
    return GetInput<PolynomialZ>(inputFunc, greetingMsg);
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to do if I called `GetInput<string, string>("hello", "greeting", "error")`? Why is your method not just generic in *one* type parameter, with the first parameter being a `Func<TRetType>`? (And why are you declaring your own delegate at all, instead of using `System.Func<T>`?)

Comment: @JonSkeet, ah, so I have to find a to tell the compiler that `inputFunc` "can be executed"?  But I only know three where constraints (new(), class and interfaces) and they don't really fit here, if this is the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet working! Thanks!!! Just learned about System.Func<T> thing.